# RFID/NFC считывание телефона

Tags: nfc

Возникла такая задача: необходимо, чтобы человек прикладывал смартфон с поддержкой NFC к RFID считывателю. Считыватель получал номер и по номеру выдавал определенную информацию. Возможно ли такое реализовать?

Comment: Думаю, что ознакомиться нужно вот с этим, к примеру: [Near Field Communication](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13092717/5275890)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, возможно. Почитайте про [Host-based Card Emulation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html).

Comment: Я так понимаю, нужно будет писать приложение для смартфона? Я хочу сделать что-то типа пропускной системы.

Comment: Да, нужно будет написать приложение для смартфона, и нужно, чтобы считыватель поддерживал тот же протокол для общения со смартфоном.

Comment: А для смартфона зачем писать софт? Если нужно просто считать с него. Про считыватель с поддержкой протокола Вы правы, а вот про приложение возник вопрос.

Comment: Хотелось бы обойтись без приложения. Думал, что считыватель может получить какой-нибудь идентификатор nfc модуля в смартфоне.

Comment: Можно и без приложения, смотря какую информацию нужно считать со смартфона. Просто если вы напишете приложение, вы будете точно уверены в том, ЧТО именно шлёт ваш смартфон считывателю. В противном случае, возможно, смартфон сможет слать только какой-нибудь рандомный UID, вы уверены, что вам нужно это?)

Comment: @Ksenia, не думаю, что будут рандомные значения. Скорее будет какой-то минимальный набор данных, которые могут быть открытыми.

Comment: @DenisBubnov, а вы пробовали на практике тестировать такое взаимодействие телефона и считывателя? :)

Comment: @Ksenia, пару лет назад, когда была подобная задача, только она касалась карт различного вида, считывал и записывал данные, но только с карт. Был подопытный телефон, но с ним возникла проблема, связанная с протоколом, считыватель не потянул его, но как я понял и как подсказывает мне логика - идентификатор, будет на подобии карточного. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @Ksenia, Видел пример открытие электронной двери в гостинице в Германии. Во время регистрации в гостинице, к считывателю подносил телефон и можно было открывать дверь в номере телефоном без какого-либо приложения.

Comment: @ИванХаритонов, а вы уверены, что там было взаимодействие на основе NFC, а не, например, bluetooth (https://geektimes.ru/post/240922/)?

Comment: @Ksenia, уверен, там даже наклейка NFC была. Хотел узнать реализацию, но языковой барьер помешал. Нашёл что-то подобное на YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sY7mI0M4Xig

Comment: @ИванХаритонов, почитайте комментарий к видео) "When sending a special command from the PC to the phone (via the NFC reader), the phone sends back its unique ID so I can make sure it's legitimate." И в конце: "Plus I'm not even sure that the ID it returns is unique." ))

Comment: И вот про эти "уникальные" ID хорошо сказано тут, в комментарии Michael Roland (а это человек, к мнению которого стоит прислушаться): 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34466238/4898850

Comment: Ну ладно, тогда эта идея отметается. Потому что делать систему пропусков с приложение не имеет никакого смысла.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что такое невозможно реализовать,т.к. NFC  и RFID   разные протоколы, не способные на взаимодействие между собой. Тут либо к смартфону подключать считыватель или эмулятор RFID  или вместо RFID  использовать NFC .